# Removing empty space from top and bottom of SVG <text> element

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a SVG `<text>` element that holds a single number glyph, e.g. 1. The `font-size` attribute is quite large: 335px. As a result, there's an ample amount of space on the top and bottom of the `<text>` element, which I would like to remove. Ideally, I would like the height of the `<text>` element to match that of its parent container, which in this case is `<svg>`.

I've tried messing around with the `dominant-baseline` attribute on the `<text>` element to no avail, but I can't seem to find any other solutions on the web.

```
<svg width="200" height="250">
    <text x="0" y="220" fill="#f6f6f6" stroke="#fbb03b" stroke-width="2" font-size="335" font-family="Hind-Regular, Hind">
        1
    </text>
</svg>
```

The picture below shows the inspection of the `<text>` element. I would like to remove the height of `<text>` element that overlaps with the red on the top and bottom of the 1 glyph.

[image: <text> element inspection]

I've attached a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9b4nk6tw/) if you would like to quickly pull up the code in a code playground.

Comment: The question is: that single glyph will always be a glyph with no descenders or ascenders? You get spaces around the number 1 because those spaces are reserved for descenders and ascenders. If you think to use only numbers you may try to convert the text to path. Alternatively you may try to use a viewBox  where you get the value by trial and error.

Comment: I believe it will always be a single number glyph. Ah yes, ascenders and descenders were the technical names I was looking for! Are there any tools you know of that can convert a text svg to a path svg?

Comment: I'm using Illustrator to convert text to outlines,

Comment: Nice. I found a great NPM package that successfully converts text into its path counterpart: https://github.com/shrhdk/text-to-svg.